# Inserting a data:image into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to insert a image into a MongoDB collection as follows-

client

```
var myInfoId = "";
myInfo.findOne({"userID": Meteor.userId()});
myInfoId = myInfoId._id;

var file = theTemplate.find('#myGraphic').files[0];
if (file)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        Meteor.call('updateMyInfo', myInfoId, e.target.result);
        console.log("file = " + e.target.result);
     }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

server

```
Meteor.methods({
    'updateMyInfo': function(myInfoId, myGraphic){
        console.log("file = " + myGraphic);
        myInfo.update (
            {"_id": myInfoId},
            {$set: {"myGraphic": myGraphic}}    
        )
    }
})
```

In both logs I can see the data as something like -

```
 file = data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ.....
```

but that data never makes it into the Collection. I set the max image size to 200x200px so the amount of data should never exceed about 24k, so I see no need to chunk up the data. What do I need to do to get that info inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at the very beginning where you set the `id`

```
var myInfoId = "";
myInfo.findOne({"userID": Meteor.userId()});
myInfoId = myInfoId._id;
```

the first line initializes a variable, the second line makes a mongo lookup but does not do anything with the result and the third line just sets the initial var to an undefined property.

```
var myInfoId = myInfo.findOne({userID: Meteor.userId()})._id;
```

This should work.

Also, since you are within the same user session (connection) on client and server, you don't need to set that from the client. In fact you can change the whole code to this:

client

```
var file = theTemplate.find('#myGraphic').files[0];
if (file)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        Meteor.call('updateMyInfo', e.target.result);
     }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

server

```
Meteor.methods({
    'updateMyInfo': function(myGraphic){
        myInfo.update (
            {myInfo.findOne({userID: Meteor.userId()})._id},
            {$set: {myGraphic: myGraphic}}    
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: Excellent answer. You not only found my mistake but gave a better method to do it. +10